# TCP Socket Server/Client in C# - Passively Receiving Data

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I've got some code in which I'm trying to receive data on response, as well as passively. However, my current attempts to receive data passively are failing. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on it for me.

```
static void Listen()
    {
        while (_socket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[2048];
                int bytesReceived = _socket.Receive(receivedBuffer);
                byte[] data = new byte[bytesReceived];

                Array.Copy(receivedBuffer, data, bytesReceived);

                Console.WriteLine("Server: \"" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data) + "\"");
            }

            catch (SocketException e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
        }
    }
```

So this was done in hopes of catching data passively from the server console when a user entered text into the console. The client is connected to the server via TCP socket. Currently this data is not being captured, and it is not hitting the catch. Rather it is remaining within the buffer which is being captured by this method.

```
static void Send()
    {
        while (_socket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Request: ");

                string request = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
                _socket.Send(buffer);

                byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[2048];
                int bytesReceived = _socket.Receive(receivedBuffer);
                byte[] data = new byte[bytesReceived];

                Array.Copy(receivedBuffer, data, bytesReceived);

                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
            }

            catch (SocketException) { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `However, my current attempts to receive data passively are failing` Maybe you want to explain what that means.....

Comment: I thought that is what I was doing by providing the code attempting to receive the data?

Comment: Code is not an explanation. Detail the expected and actual behavior.

Comment: I did my best to try to elaborate - if you still want more information, let me know.

Comment: In TCP Bytes sent != Bytes received in all cases. If you send two messages `123`, `456` on the other end you might get 2 messages `123`, `456` or you might get `12`, `3456` or you might get  `12`, `34`, `56`. You need to "frame" your messages, either by putting on some kind of terminator that you check for (`\n` and `\0` are popular choices) or by sending the length of the string before you send the string itself. That way the receiving side can tell where one message ends and another begins.

Comment: What's with that empty catch? Remove it. How will you find out about errors? This code will work in principle. There is some other problem.